# Creating progress bar from dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>
<span class="dot"></span>

.dot {
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #FAE089;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/duauvyrv/

My question is, what could be the best way making a countdown timer from those dots by changing color?

Example: Count down from 10 seconds, and change dot from yellow to grey. If timer is up, all the dots should be grey as well.

Comment: This depends on how you want it to look? Do you want it to look like a progress bar where bars go yellow to grey starting from left to right or do you want all dots to gradually go yellow to grey in color?

Comment: Research `setInterval()`. All you need to do is to add a class to the elements in order of their index.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Let's say left to right

Comment: Don't even need `setInterval()` as you could just use [jQuery UI animate](https://jqueryui.com/animate/) over 10 seconds.  It's a one liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me it is better to create dots also by JS.

```js
var n = 28;
var time = 10000;
var progress = document.querySelector('.dots');
var dot = [];
var counter = n - 1;

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  dot[i] = document.createElement('div');
  dot[i].classList.add('dot');
  progress.appendChild(dot[i]);
}

var go = setInterval(function() {
  if (!counter) clearInterval(go);
  dot[counter].style.background = 'gray';
  counter--;
}, time / n)
```

```css
.dot {
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dots"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't laugh at my suggestion:

```js
    var index = 28;
    
    setInterval(function() {
      index--;
      document.getElementById("custom-style").innerHTML = ".dots .dot:nth-child(-n + " + index + "){background-color: #FF0;}"
    },1000)
```

```css
    .dot {
      height: 5px;
      width: 5px;
      background-color: #aaa;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
    <style id='custom-style'>.dots .dot:nth-child(-n + 28){background-color: #FF0;}</style>

    <div class="dots">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: its adding on click and not timer/interval

Comment: :D it still doesnt setback to grey

Comment: Thanks, seems like to be a solution for me. Had one more question, if I show the timer on the site 5..4..3..2..1..0 and once it hits 0, dots should also be all "done". Is such thing possible?

Comment: @LewisLarf yep, but i think that next part is for you to work out. All the code needed is there (document, getElementById, the HTML, innerHTML, etc) you just need to tweak it

Answer (score 0):

You can a combination of `delay()` and `queue()` to make it work. By dividing the number of elements by 10 seconds, we can get the per-element delay, then delay each one by that amount.

```js
//Get delay interval
var count = $("#dots span").length;
var speed = 10000/count;
$("#dots span").each(function(index){
 $(this).delay(speed*index).queue(function(next){
   $(this).css('background-color', 'gray');
    next();
  });
});
```

```css
.dot {
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #FAE089;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dots">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're wanting each dot to gradually change color after a specific time, see my answer below:

After each `setTimeout` you want to add another 10 seconds. Otherwise all dots will change color at the same time.

`$(this)` is referring to the specific `dot` element you're looping through.

```
let countdown = 10000;

$(".dot").each(function(index){
    setTimeout(() => {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#ddd');
    }, countdown);

    countdown += 10000;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Can be done as follows.

```
var amount = $(".dot").length;
var timer = amount/10*100;
var elementIndex = 0;

var progress = setInterval(function (){
var element = ".dot:eq(" + elementIndex + ")";
    $(element).css("background", "grey");
++elementIndex;
if(elementIndex > amount){
clearInterval(progress);
}
},timer);
progress();
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/9zr3kysz/3/

(Im currently in mobile and seemingly cant make a code snippet from that).

PS. Change the styling as you wish. Using `.css` is not the most performant way, but just an example.

Another example with a "done flash" can be seen here https://jsfiddle.net/9zr3kysz/4/